# PUT method and payload with devbridge Jquery Autocomplete Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I'm using the devbridge autocomplete plugin for JQuery.

So far I'm able to call my Rest API and get some results. My Rest Api accepts a query using the PUT methode. But basically I need to pass the value of my textfield (customer) in the query.

Basically I need to update the value of the data payload everytime the value changes. But  $( "#customer" ).val() is empty when I trace it the developer console.

I think I dont use it in the correct way. The service shoudl return all results and then it's filtered in the earch box. But for some reasons when I type something in the search box its not filtered. I have all the results in the list box.

I tried the following code but it doesnt work.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#customer" ).devbridgeAutocomplete({
            serviceUrl: 'http://localhost:8080/services/rest/data/Customer/query',
            type: 'PUT',
            dataType: 'text',
            ajaxSettings: {
                'data': '{"select": {"from": ["Customer"],"where": {"full_text": [{"value": "'+$( "#customer" ).val()+'"}]}}}',
                'contentType': 'application/json',
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': 'Basic YXXtXX5pcXXyYXRvXXphZG1pbmlzdHJhdG9y'
                },
            },
            transformResult: function(response) {
                var responseObj = jQuery.parseJSON( response );

                return { suggestions: $.map(responseObj, function(data) {
                    return { value: data.customer.fullname, data: data.customer.mdmcustid };
                })};
            },
            onSelect: function (suggestion) {
                console.log('You selected: ' + suggestion.value + ', ' + suggestion.data);
            },
            onSearchStart: function (query) {
                console.log('Search terms: ' + $( "#customer" ).val());
            }
    });
});
</script>
```

Can you tell me how to fix this ?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

it's working using a custom lookup but I dont know if it's the best method.

```
lookup: function (query, done) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "PUT",
                url: "http://localhost:8080/talendmdm/services/rest/data/Customer/query",
                contentType: "application/json",
                data: '{"select": {"from": ["Customer"],"where": {"full_text": [{"value": "'+$( "#customer" ).val()+'"}]}}}',
                dataType: "text",
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': 'Basic YWRtaW5pc3RyYXRvcjphZG1pbmlzdHJhdG9y'
                },
                success: function (res) {
                    var suggestionObj = { suggestions: $.map(jQuery.parseJSON( res ), function(data) {
                        return { value: data.customer.fullname, data: data.customer.mdmcustid };
                    })};

                    done(suggestionObj);
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    console.log( 'Query KO' );
                }
            });
        },
        onSelect: function (suggestion) {
            console.log('You selected: ' + suggestion.value + ', ' + suggestion.data);
        }
```